# Is there a way to deploy exploded bundles in Apache Felix?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi

We are looking at rearchitecting our web application and want to move to a more modular solution, OSGi seems to meet a lot of our needs.

I've come across the Apache Felix project and taken it for a spin. It looks solid yet I find the development cycle a bit slow as it requires a maven build of the bundle(s) to make any code changes effective.

Instead I would like to be able to reload a bundle once classes have been compiled by Eclipse, without any extra building/packaging. Similar to how Tomcat and other servlet containers support deployment of "exploded" war files.

Is this possible to do with Felix or any other OSGi container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Gogo shell, you can do:

```
install reference:file:/path/to/exploded/directory
```

This will install an exploded bundle. The format of the exploded directory should be exact that of a bundle JAR file.

Comment: Ok, that works. But how to automate this? I presume you can invoke a gogo shell command from an Eclipse launch task but I have no idea how to go about that. Typing in the console every time is not so convenient...

Comment: See my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733822/deploy-exploded-bundle-to-apache-felix-using-an-eclipse-launch-task question about this.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Felix FileInstall](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html) supports exploded bundles out of the box. Just install it, and put a directory with your bundle in the `load` directory (or configure FileInstall to look somewhere else).

Not exactly answering your question, but if you have issues with the build cycle, you should take a look at [bndtools](http://njbartlett.name/bndtools.html), which is a plugin for Eclipse that a.o. automatically builds and deploys your bundles in a running framework when your code changes.